# PHP / MySQL publish content with different layouts

Tags: php, mysql, html, wysiwyg

I am building a website that includes a news management system, using PHP and MySQL

The system works perfectly. Basically I insert records into the database, then output them with a .php script formatted so that content look nice.

**My problem**: News published like this, can only be outputted every time the same way, I mean, you can output somthing like this image:

[image: Image 1]

Then all news will have the same above layout that the .php script for retrieving db records gives them.

**My question**: Is there any easy way / system / whatever, that allows user to publish things every time with different layouts? Maybe something like:

[image: Image 2]

I use a WYSIWYG editor to publish news... But that only allows user to change font-color, justify, left, right text-align, inserting images, and so on...

Thank you!

Comment: for that better use CSS and apply width or add in table for `title` and `date` column

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to preload the layout into the wysiwyg?  If so, you can simply create a new db table containing your layouts and echo them into the wysiwyg when a user creates a new article.

Comment: Maybe that could be a good option. Still, user could only use a few pre-formatted layouts. But thanks!

Comment: A user could use an infinite number of layouts being as they are being pulled from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of php conditionals and css styling:

A simple example (using ternary operators to keep it short...):

php:

```
$title_class = empty($date) ? '' : 'with_date';
echo "<h1 class='{$title_class}'>{$title}</h1>"
echo empty($date) ? '' : "<span class='date'>{$date}</span>";
// etc.
```

css:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h1.with_date {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.date {
  float: right;
}
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks @jeroen, but that only allows the second example layout. I'd like to produce any layout...

Comment: @qalbiol It's just a simple example, if you want more complicated layouts, you would need to make some templates and pick one based on for example a field in your news-item.